# What are some must-have equipment in a mobile fieldwork kit?

Tags: methodology, field-linguistics

Suppose you are given a $35,000 budget for documentation equipment to perform a typological study of suprasegmental features of language varieties spoken in urban and rural Finland.

Obviously, one needs:

1. a voice recorder to record speech;
2. an external microphone
3. a video camera to capture gesture (why not, you already have $35,000!) and tripod
4. a small laptop for on-site analysis (with a license to some software besides Praat?)
5. a pair of headphones
6. a hard case to carry this stuff in

Would appreciate any insight into brand names/types and/or additional things y'all recommend.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends in part on the intended use, i.e. recording a village meeting is quite different from well-controlled elicitation with one person.

I recommend a [Fostex FR 2LE recorder](http://www.fostexinternational.com/docs/products/FR-2LE.shtml). You need at least a head-mounted mic (for the interviewee), and possibly a pair of mics on stands (if you're recording more than one person at a time). I would recommend the Audix headset (but mine doesn't have a number on it). One problem I've encountered is that the headband assembly can be too small, which is a problem if you're working with someone that has a big melon. The other problem (probably a bad luck one) is that the first one (don't remember the brand) I got was way too hot (problems adjusting the input level). Shure has head mics that are more expandable and adjustable, but somewhat prone to becoming permanently floppy.

For a pair of mics, I would say that it doesn't matter much as long as you spend about $100+ each. Blue makes nice mics. You can get some really nice mics for $20,000 and big deal, you're gonna have truck and monkey noise (if there are monkeys) anyhow. If your sound source is in fixed location, you probably want a unidirectional mic, but if it's all around you, go for an omnidirectional. The other main variable is condenser vs. dynamic. Dynamic mics are more robust but condensers are better for "get the speaker, not the noise". Since you are a rich man, don't decide, get both kinds. And use a [deadcat (microphone cover)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Blimps). I also suggest redundancy: multiple mics are wise, get enough SD cards, have replacement cables. There are multiple issues related to power requirements (the big one being, will you have power?).

Mic stands are important (don't have a speaker holding the mic, they will fiddle with it). I also suggest acoustic foam / insulation that you could easily put up to improve room acoustics (it applicable) -- sheets / panels, rather than lots of little tiles. Clearly not applicable to the village meeting, but very useful if interviewing a person in a room with concrete walls and nothing on them.

{ADDED:}
Actually, one standard solution is to use blankets. I've used 2" Owens-Corning fiberglass but that's not transportable (and it's kind of icky). 1/2" foam padding should do it, and it's cheap enough that you could do a test beforehand and try again if that doesn't work.

Comment: Very practical answer!

Comment: Great ideas, excellent input and useful experience. You're the best. Thanks. Do you have any suggestions for acoustic foam/insulation that is transportable?

Answer (score 0):

In the past, useful surveys have been done by enlisting the help of many teachers in local schools.  Maybe you could get lots of data quickly by buying lots of little digital recorders and sending them to school teachers, with instructions about what you'd like them to record from their students for you.  There should be some payback, with you sending all the teachers the results of your study, which they could then share with their students.